# Outputting anonymous types from Linq GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to output an anonymous type from a GroupJoin in LINQ but one query works and another one doesn't.

The only difference is in the first query the starting `service` is an in memory IGrouping (a member from a previous call to GroupBy) instead of a direct database query.

The error I'm getting is

> Error 8   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoin(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.   C:\Users\wbutt\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ServiceGraphMonitor\Controllers\ServiceQueueController.cs  148 30  ServiceGraphMonitor

This is the query that doesn't work:

```
var result = index.GroupJoin(service.GroupBy(
    s => new
    {
        h = s.orig_que_dt.Hour,
        s = s.orig_que_dt.Minute / 15
    }
    ), i => i, s => s.Key,
    (i, s) => new
    {
        x = new DateTime(start_date.Year, start_date.Month, start_date.Day, i.h, i.m * 15, 0),
        y = s.Count()
    }
);
```

This one works:

```
var result = index.GroupJoin(db.t_svc_task_sta.Where(ts =>
    ts.t_svc_task.orig_que_dt > start_date &&
    ts.t_svc_task.orig_que_dt < end_date
    ).GroupBy(ts => new
    {
        h = ts.t_svc_task.orig_que_dt.Hour,
        m = ts.t_svc_task.orig_que_dt.Minute / 15
    }
    ), i => i, ts => ts.Key,
    (i, ts) => new // DTO.ServiceReport()
    {
        time = new DateTime(start_date.Year, start_date.Month, start_date.Day, i.h, i.m * 15, 0).ToUniversalTime(),
        queue_time = ts.Sum(t => t.Where(x => x.svc_task_sta_cd == 1 && x.sta_end_dt <= DateTime.Now).DefaultIfEmpty(new t_svc_task_sta() {sta_start_dt = DateTime.Today, sta_end_dt = DateTime.Today }).Average(x => (x.sta_end_dt - x.sta_start_dt).TotalSeconds)),
        exec_time = ts.Sum(t => t.Where(x => x.svc_task_sta_cd == 2 && x.sta_end_dt <= DateTime.Now).DefaultIfEmpty(new t_svc_task_sta() {sta_start_dt = DateTime.Today, sta_end_dt = DateTime.Today }).Average(x => (x.sta_end_dt - x.sta_start_dt).TotalSeconds)),
        volume = ts.Sum(t => t.Count(x => x.svc_task_sta_cd == 1))
    }
);
```

Comment: You have 's' defined twice.

Comment: You're right. I'm using 's' to denote minutes in an anonymous class for a key comparator... This is what happens when I skip my afternoon coffee break. Thanks!